# Invoke two separate build scripts as a matrix on Travis CI

Tags: maven, build-process, travis-ci

I'd like to run Travis CI builds for two different build scripts. For example something like that:

- `./prepare.sh
  mvn verify -Psystem-tests`
- `./prepare.sh
  mvn verify -Pintegration-tests`

In [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Matrix) I see that Build Matrix feature is exactly what I need, but samples there refer only how to create matrix over different environments.

How can I create such matrix over different build commands?

Here's my current `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.m2
script:
  - ./prepare.sh
  - mvn verify -Psystem-tests
  - mvn clean verify -Pintegration-tests
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `matrix` section, you can specify either:

- the commands themselves:

  ```
  matrix:
    - env: MAVEN_SCRIPT="mvn verify -Psystem-tests"
    - env: MAVEN_SCRIPT="mvn clean verify -Pintegration-tests"
  script:
    - ./prepare.sh
    - $MAVEN_SCRIPT
  ```
- which command to run, and then `if` on them:

  ```
  matrix:
    - env: MAVEN_TESTS=system
    - env: MAVEN_TESTS=integration
  script:
    - ./prepare.sh
    - if [ "$MAVEN_TESTS" == "system" ]; then mvn verify -Psystem-tests; fi
    - if [ "$MAVEN_TESTS" == "integration" ]; then mvn clean verify -Pintegration-tests; fi
  ```
- the specific parts that differentiate the tests:

  ```
  matrix:
    - env: MAVEN_TEST_CLEANLINESS=""    MAVEN_TESTS=system
    - env: MAVEN_TEST_CLEANLINESS=clean MAVEN_TESTS=integration
  script:
    - ./prepare.sh
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLEANLINESS verify -P$MAVEN_TESTS-tests
  ```